# Setting a default http host with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to set my API host as the default host, e.g. http://example.com/v1, so that I don't have to specify the full url in every $http or $resource request?  That way I can use relative URLs.

Comment: While not an answer to your question, I think [this looks promising](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/929).

Comment: $http and $resource do work with relative urls.

Comment: Here is a solution using a service: http://blog.busymachines.com/frontend/angularjs/2013/07/16/managing-api-urls-in-angularjs.html

Answer (score 0):

I looked for something like that and came up empty. In the end I really didn't want that because it would prevent me from hitting APIs other than the one specified host. What I ended up doing is I created a constant with the API url which I would then inject in any service that needs it. Something like this:

```
angular.module('admin').constant('ApiUrl', 'http://example.com/v1');
```

which could go on your module file, and then on a service:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('admin')
    .factory('SampleFactory', SampleFactory);

SampleFactory.$inject = ['$resource', 'ApiUrl'];

function SampleFactory($resource, ApiUrl) {
    var resource = $resource(ApiUrl + 'cohort/:id', {}, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
    return resource;
}
})();
```